# Google Line Chart Material Curve

Tags: google-visualization

I have been trying to migrate some existing charts to the newer Google Material view however the Line chart won't allow me to display it with a curved line.

You can see their new chart half way down this link:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Just wondering if anyone has found a way to get this working?

And yes, i am including this in my JSON options:

```
curveType: 'function',
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have been using the material charts for bar charts, and frankly not all options are supported yet. I did some brief experimenting and I would guess that curved lines are just not supported for material charts yet. I would be sure to keep trying the options conversion code `google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options)`  listed here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: Thats exactly what i'm doing, thanks buddy. I have to say that i'm not all that impressed with Google in this case as they aren't making the roadmap clear at all!

Comment: Yes, seems that the function curve type is not supported yet for material charts.

Answer (score 2):

the list of features not working in *Material* charts can be found here...

[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

which includes...

`curveType`
`series.*.curveType`